# How I can make a static map with google-map-react in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-map-react

I have this :

```
 <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'key' }}
      defaultCenter={center}
      defaultZoom={zoom}
>
  <TacoMarker
   link={shop.id}
   lat={latitude}
   lng={longitude}
  />

 </GoogleMapReact>
```

What props can I pass you? Would it be like a scrollEnabled = {false}?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`google-map-react` is written to use [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview). Please note that Maps JavaScript API is different from [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start). If you would like to show a static map in your react code, you can just directly put the [Maps Static API URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#URL_Parameters) in the `src` parameter of your `<img/>` tag.

Here's a sample code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Static Maps Sample</h1>
      <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=YOUR_API_KEY"/>   
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```